# Syntax error when inserting strings into MySQL using PyMySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I frequently use pymysql to insert data into a MySQL server.

When inserting strings, I usually (but not every time) receive: pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, ...) when I insert a string using the code (where  refers to a varchar):

```
cursor.execute("Insert into table (column) values (%s)", (stringVar))
```

Typically I have to do something like:

```
cursor.execute("Insert into table (column) values ('"+stringVar+"')"))
```

However, sometimes that throws the same error and I have to do something like:

```
stringVar="'"+stringVar                          
stringVar=stringVar+"'"          
cursor.execute("Insert into table (column) values ("+stringVar+")")
```

This just isn't a feasible way to program this operation.

I assume I am messing up something simple but I cannot figure out what this is.  I use pymysql a lot and this error is really starting to wear on me.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please format your code, and include your full error messages.

Comment: Try `cursor.execute("Insert into table table_name (column) values (?)", (stringVar,))`

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (?)', (stringVar,))
```

Whenever you're trying to directly format a string into a query like that, it's basically always a sign you're doing something wrong. Every python database interface I'm aware of has a way to pass parameters to queries like above. Note that having the `stringVar` contained within an iterable is required.